# Facing errors while installing openEdx

Tags: devstack, openedx, edx

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket.
After cloning the **make dev.clone** error occurs while executing **"make dev.provision"**. i am working `Ubuntu 20.04 EC2` instance.

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxwHl.png)

Comment: which version of openedx are you using?

Comment: I am working on Lilac

Comment: have you tried with sudo ?  sudo make dev.provision

Comment: yes, i do tried with sudo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command instead of make dev.clone

```
make dev.clone.https
```

It will defiantly work fine. I was facing the same error and solved by this.
and please make sure that you are passing the following environmental variable each time when you pass any make command

```
export OPENEDX_RELEASE=lilac.master
```

when you pass any make command like make dev.up or clone, it's really important to set the environmental variable to set the branch.